# ListView within ListActivity automatically scrolls up to first item each time new items are appended during infinite scroll

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, infinite-scroll

As you can see in my Activity and Adapter class below, I implemented an infinite ListView scroll for calling an API. It is obvious that, I want to show the last items appending to the listview after each scroll, but the problem is, the listView automatically starts to scroll up to it's fist item each time the new items added. How can I solve that?

```
public class AdvertisementAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Advertisement> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Advertisement> advertisementList;

    public AdvertisementAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Advertisement> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.advertisementList = objects;
        }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = 
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_advertisement, parent, false);

        Advertisement advertisement = advertisementList.get(position);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(advertisement.getTitle());

        return view;
    }


}



 public class Home extends ListActivity implements OnScrollListener {
        TextView output;
        List<MyTask> tasks;
        String uri = "http://MyHost.com/x/y/z";
        int pageIndex = 1;
        int pageSize = 10;

        List<Advertisement> advertisementList;
        AdvertisementAdapter adapter;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.home);
            getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
            tasks = new ArrayList<>();

            requestData(uri);

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // empty
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView listView, int scrollState) {

            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= listView.getCount() - 1)
                {
                    pageIndex++;
                    getData();
                    }
                }


            private void requestData(String uri) {

                RequestPackage p = new RequestPackage();
                p.setMethod("GET");
                p.setUri(uri);
                p.setParam("pageindex", Integer.toString(pageIndex));
                p.setParam("pagesize", Integer.toString(pageSize));

                MyTask task = new MyTask();
                task.execute(p);
            }

            protected void updateDisplay() {

                if (adapter != null)
            {
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else
                {
                   adapter = new AdvertisementAdapter(this,R.layout.item_advertisement,     advertisementList); 
                }

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            }

            private class MyTask extends
                    AsyncTask<RequestPackage, String, List<Advertisement>> {

                @Override

                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    tasks.add(this);
                }

                @Override
                protected List<Advertisement> doInBackground(RequestPackage... params) {

                    String content = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);

                    if (advertisementList == null) 
                    {
                        advertisementList = AdvertisementJSONParser.parseJson(content);
                    } else 
                    {
                        advertisementList.addAll(AdvertisementJSONParser.parseJson(content));
                    }

                    return advertisementList;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(List<Advertisement> result) {

                    tasks.remove(this);
                    advertisementList = result;
                    updateDisplay();

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: I think the title is misleading, there is no last element in an infinite list :) --- That been said, I'm not really sure what do you mean; Where would you want to stop it, and why is it infinite if it should stop?

Comment: @TacBoss: for example there is 50 items in listview. then user scrolls it and 10 items will be add to previous items. so I need to show 51-60th items as current itesm. but the listview shows 1-9the items. I'm sure there is something wrong in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in `updateDisplay()`

```
protected void updateDisplay() {
if (adapter != null)
   {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   } else {
    adapter = new AdvertisementAdapter(this,R.layout.item_advertisement, advertisementList);
    setListAdapter(adapter); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not create new `adapter` each time you must append the data to your `adapter` data set and call `notifyDataSetChange` that means:

```
if (adapter != null){
   adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
}else{
   adapter = new AdvertisementAdapter(this,R.layout.item_advertisement, advertisementList); 
}
```

Comment: If you take a look and updateDisplay() method in Home class you can see I exactly did it. I just tested the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in else clause but it can't help.

Comment: i look and see nothing; no notifydatasetChange?

Comment: first, I'm very thankful because of your help. but the main problem was setListAdapter(adapter) function which was out of If condition.